# Laptop battery drains really fast after firmware update. 10 hours life to 2.5 hours

Tags: updates, firmware, battery-life

An automatic update on my windows laptop happened the morning of July 25. I believe the update was: 2017-06 Update for Windows 10 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems (KB4022405). It stated that the firmware was being updated and it took about 2 hours to install.

Evening of July 25 and July 26 my laptop's battery only lasted 2.5 hours without being plugged in. Before the update it lasted about 10 hours. I have not changed my usage habits, what can this change be related to?

Comment: Perhaps it changed the power scheme used in Windows?

Comment: What laptop? What firmware? Please edit your question to add necessary information to aid us in finding the right answer for you.